# Designing a 8x8 grid game, looking for example rules

Tags: game-design

I am designing a *very* simple board game, the intention is that it will be played by providing an AI script, rather than played directly (though you could play it.)

Basic idea:

- 8x8 board
- each player has a single board piece
- pieces face in a direction (N / S / E / W)

At each turn players:

- optionally rotate their piece 90 degrees either direction
- take an action, one of

  - move one tile in the direction faced
  - shoot in the direction faced

When a player is 'shot', the other player wins.

The rules of this game are so simple I feel there must be a lot of other examples. Can someone point me to other similar example rulesets like this?

Comment: You seem to have described a decent rule set here.  What is it you are looking for?

Comment: It would be fun to run this in a simulator. I think you can be trapped very easy and the start player has a certain advantage.

Comment: Well maybe! I wonder if there is a body of work I am missing that I can look at. I am not at all attached to the rules I've described, maybe they would not even work.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe, running this as a simulator and allowing users to add their scripts is exactly my intention.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe, problems like being trapped and first mover advantage spoiling it is exactly the problems I'm worried about

Comment: Definitely not exactly the same, but this has some similarities to Onitama.

Answer (score 2):

Roborally does this on a far more complex scale.

Here you program the pieces 5 steps ahead and the board has obstacles, moving elements and traps. The board is also bigger and you have to complete a route in order to win.
Next you have some hitpoints so you won't die with one shot.